# Rspec fails with ActionController::UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Rspec fails with `ActionController::UrlGenerationError` with a URL I would think is valid. I've tried messing with the params of Rspec request, as well as fiddled with the routes.rb, but I'm still missing something.

The weird thing is, it works 100% as expected when testing locally with curl.

**Error:**

```
Failure/Error: get :index, {username: @user.username}
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"api/v1/users/devices", :username=>"isac_mayer"}
```

**Relevant code:**

*spec/api/v1/users/devices_controller_spec.rb*

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Api::V1::Users::DevicesController, type: :controller do

    before do
        @user = FactoryGirl::create :user
        @device = FactoryGirl::create :device
        @user.devices << @device
        @user.save!
    end

    describe "GET" do
        it "should GET a list of devices of a specific user" do
            get :index, {username: @user.username}  # <= Fails here, regardless of params. (Using FriendlyId by the way)
            # expect..
        end
    end
end
```

*app/controllers/api/v1/users/devices_controller.rb*

```
class Api::V1::Users::DevicesController < Api::ApiController
  respond_to :json

  before_action :authenticate, :check_user_approved_developer

  def index
    respond_with @user.devices.select(:id, :name)
  end

end
```

*config/routes.rb*

```
  namespace :api, path: '', constraints: {subdomain: 'api'}, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :checkins, only: [:create]
      resources :users do
        resources :approvals, only: [:create], module: :users
        resources :devices, only: [:index, :show], module: :users
      end
    end
  end
```

Relevant line from `rake routes`

```
api_v1_user_devices GET    /v1/users/:user_id/devices(.:format)        api/v1/users/devices#index {:format=>"json", :subdomain=>"api"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index action requires a `:user_id` parameter, but you haven't supplied one in the params hash. Try:

```
get :index, user_id: @user.id
```

The error message is a bit confusing, because you aren't actually supplying a URL; instead you are calling the `#get` method on the test controller, and passing it a list of arguments, the first one is the action (`:index`), and the second is the params hash.

Controller specs are unit tests for controller actions, and they expect that the request parameters are correctly specified. Routing is not the responsibility of the controller; if you want to verify that a particular URL is routed to the right controller action (since as you mention, you are using friendly-id), you may want to consider a [routing spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/routing-specs).

Comment: You're a star. One of those things that's pretty obvious, but I assumed wasn't the issue! Ended up using `get :index, user_id: @user.username`